# Is there a way in lotus notes to have a global (to a document) error handler?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I've inherited a lotus notes application and one of the things that really irks me is every function/sub/property has onerror statements and errorhandler labels that aside from typos all do the exact same thing. Additionally, and unfortunately this application has gone through several revisions and some errorhandler: labels have revisions where as other don't. I'd like to standardize and centralize this behavior.

Is there a way to have a single error handler for a given document, where if an error is raised anywhere in the document, that particular error handler is called?

Thank you,

Comment: http://searchdomino.techtarget.com/tip/Structured-error-handling-in-LotusScript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have one error handler per script execution.  You cannot have one global to a document. Each event that fires in a document results in a new script execution.

That said, it is generally advantageous to have one error handler per function, but that advantage is lost if they are actually exactly the same. The better practice is to customize them so that each error handler records the name of the current function. (Of course, due to copy/paste laziness, this is frequently more effective in theory than in practice.)

Answer (score 0):

If you have an `On Error Goto SomeLabel` statement (where `SomeLabel` is whatever label the code actually uses), the label must exist in the same Sub/Function that contains that statement so, technically, you need a separate handler for each Sub/Function.

However, some things might simplify matters...

If one Sub/Function calls another Sub/Function, and the inner one doesn't have an error handler but the outer one (the caller) does, then an error in the inner Sub/Function will be caught by the handler in the caller.
This setup gives you less information (you can't get the line number on which the error occurred in the inner Sub/Function), but it might be helpful if you have any Subs/Functions that you're sure either can't produce an error, or only have one line on which an error could occur.

If you have some static message-text or logging which is identical in many error handlers, you could have a Sub/Function in the Form Globals (or in a script library to absolutely minimise code duplication) that contains the static parts of the error handlers, and takes arguments for the variable parts (error message, line number, and Sub/Function name).

Finally, this code will produce the name of the current Sub/Function and makes it easier to use the same error handler in many places, as long as the code declarations contain `%include "lsconst.lss"` or you use a script library containing the same `%include` statement:

`GetThreadInfo(LSI_THREAD_PROC)`

Another function, `LSI_Info`, can also give you the name of the current Sub/Function, but isn't supported by IBM, and should be avoided.